# App crashes when i click on checkbox in contact listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, custom-adapter, android-checkbox

I am new android Developer and i want to select multiple contacts in list view using check box but yet when i click any check box app is crashed I am Using a custom Adapter plz any one can help me

my contactList ACtivity is following

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhoneList> {
    int inflatr;
    Context ctxt;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> data=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PhoneList> arr) {

        super(context, resource, arr);
        this.inflatr = resource;
        this.ctxt = context;
        this.data= arr;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserHolder holder = null;
         View row = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(inflatr, parent, false);
             holder = new UserHolder();
             holder.textName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
             holder.stnumber=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mobilenum);
             holder.checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);
//           holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
             row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
             holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();            
        }


         PhoneList dta=data.get(position);
         holder.checked.setId(position);
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    zoooommmm"+dta.getNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for(int i=1; i<=256; i++)
        {
            holder.textName.setText(dta.getName());
        }
        for(int j=1; j<=256; j++)
        {
            holder.stnumber.setText(dta.getNumber());
        }
//      holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    Siddiqueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+dta.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),ContactList.class);
//              String tName=dta.getName();
//              moreIntent.putExtra("Template",tName);
//              v.getContext().startActivity(moreIntent);
//               // ctxt.startActivity(ctxt,ContactList.class);
//          }
//      });
        return row;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;
        TextView textLocation;
        ImageButton btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
        TextView stnumber;
        CheckBox checked;
        }


}
```

my custom adapter is following

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhoneList> {
    int inflatr;
    Context ctxt;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> data=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PhoneList> arr) {

        super(context, resource, arr);
        this.inflatr = resource;
        this.ctxt = context;
        this.data= arr;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserHolder holder = null;
         View row = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(inflatr, parent, false);
             holder = new UserHolder();
             holder.textName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
             holder.stnumber=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mobilenum);
             holder.checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);
//           holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
             row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
             holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();            
        }


         PhoneList dta=data.get(position);
         holder.checked.setId(position);
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    zoooommmm"+dta.getNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for(int i=1; i<=256; i++)
        {
            holder.textName.setText(dta.getName());
        }
        for(int j=1; j<=256; j++)
        {
            holder.stnumber.setText(dta.getNumber());
        }
//      holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    Siddiqueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+dta.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),ContactList.class);
//              String tName=dta.getName();
//              moreIntent.putExtra("Template",tName);
//              v.getContext().startActivity(moreIntent);
//               // ctxt.startActivity(ctxt,ContactList.class);
//          }
//      });
        return row;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;
        TextView textLocation;
        ImageButton btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
        TextView stnumber;
        CheckBox checked;
        }


}
```

My phoneList Class is ..

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

public class PhoneList {
    String name;
    String number;
    public PhoneList(String string,String number) {
        super();
        this.name = string;
        this.number=number;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
        }
    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
        this.number=number;
    }
    public String getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        }



}
```

xml layout of List View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
    >
    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:divider="#FFEEEE" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/lvContacts"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

xml layout of each row in a List View

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_header" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="32dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/face" >
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#04b3d2"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobilenum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="03455039469"
            android:textColor="#04b3d2"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/shape"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error is following....

```
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x4
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceEntryName(Resources.java:1756)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3590)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-12 13:30:32.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25447):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: yes that name is check  which mention in the line  holder.checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);

Comment: PhoneList dta=data.get(position);
         holder.checked.setId(position);

here you have changed the id of the checkbox. So that there were no respective id in the R.java file. Thats the reason for getting the exception.

Comment: exception solved by using code holder.checked.setTag(position); but multiple rows chcekboxes checked

Comment: Avoid using holder for checkbox. Remove the checkbox from the holder class and inflate it as usual.

Comment: plzz tell me some in  details

Comment: Check my answer and let me know the result..

Comment: Post your layout XML. Problem is in a `android:onClick` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you changed id of `checkbox` in your code?

```
 holder.checked.setId(position);
```

if you want keep position in your `checkbox` use `Tag` instead of `id`

you can use:

```
holder.checked.setTag(position);
```

and for getting that:

```
int position = (Integer)holder.checked.getTag();
```

as you change id of checkbox in your code you get **Resources$NotFoundException** because you changed id of checkbox to 1,2,3,4,... and this not saved in R file,

**// UPDATE**

multiple select item happened because [listviews-recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works), for solving this issue you need save selected position in one place or you can do:

add following property to `PhoneList`

```
boolean isSelected;
```

create getter and setter method for that.

```
public boolean getIsSelected()
{
  return isSelected;
}


public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected)
{
   this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
```

then in your code in `getView` method use:

```
 holder.checked.setChecked(dta.getIsSelected());
```

and in click of checkbox change value of `isSelected` to `!isSelected`:

so your code must be like:

```
 holder.checked.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in `onClick` method:

```
 data.get((Integer)v.getTag()).setIsSelected(!data.get((Integer)v.getTag()).getIsSelected);
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: broo that working but one thing when i click on this multiple check box rows is selected how to correct this

Comment: I don't get you, can you describe better. what is your mean about `rows is selected`?

Comment: that code holder.checked.setTag(position); when i uae this my app not crashed but after clicking when saw all rows of contact list multiple rows checked

Comment: see my Edit, and if this solved your problem tick that as answer, if you don't get your answer ask another question with new problem because this problem not related to this question

Comment: I added more details for you, see my Edit again

Comment: I posted A xml layout plz tell why multiple check boxes checked when click one check box

Comment: naii but as you telling me this is another question and click on answer then as a behalf of your respect i clicked but edit post is not solved my problem can you alaborate setter and gettr

Comment: if you dont get your answer ask another question, post new code and notify me, I must see your code

Comment: please broo check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606086/multiple-checkboxes-checked-when-one-check-a-one-check-box

Answer (score 0):

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:` will throw whenever you request a id which is not available for you.

The Layout which you inflating doesn't have id named `check`. So you need to check the `XML` file. If its not there include it. It will resolve your problem.

```
 `holder.checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes

```
 static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;
        TextView textLocation;
        ImageButton btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
        TextView stnumber;
       //removed checkbox here
        }
```

and

```
 //Added checkbox here
 CheckBox checked;
 if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(inflatr, parent, false);
             holder = new UserHolder();
             holder.textName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
             holder.stnumber=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mobilenum);
//removed    holder.checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check); this line
//           holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
             row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
             holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();            
        } 


  //And added this line
    checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);
```