# multiple checkboxes checked when one check a one check box

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am a New Android Developer and when I click on one check-box multiple check-boxes are checked in multiple rows, I am using a custom adapter, please can anyone help me?

My Contact List is following ..

```
public class ContactList extends Activity {
    ListView lvContacts;
      List<String> listname;  
      List<String> listnumber;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> arr;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> arrnumber;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            String[] projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    };
            Cursor c1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null, null);


            // Let activity manage the cursor

            //startManagingCursor(c1);


            listname = new ArrayList<String>();
            listnumber = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (c1.moveToNext())
            {
              String name=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
              String number = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              listname.add(name);
              listnumber.add(number);


            }
            c1.close();
//          while(c1.moveToNext())
//          {
//              //Log.d("fghfh", ""+c1.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
//              String name=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
//              String  number=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
//              //System.out.println(".................."+number); 




               // Log.d("Contacts : ",name);//+":"+number);
            //}
             Object[] obj=listname.toArray();
             Object[] objnumber=listnumber.toArray();
          //   arrnumber=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
             arr=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
             String[] da=new String[obj.length];
             String[] danumber=new String[objnumber.length];

             for(int i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
            {    
                 danumber[i]=(String)objnumber[i];
                 da[i]=(String)obj[i];
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Humayoon    zoom"+obj[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 arr.add(new PhoneList(da[i],danumber[i]));


            }
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
            CustomAdapter adpttt=new CustomAdapter(ContactList.this,R.layout.contacts_list_item,arr);
            listView.setAdapter(adpttt);
}
}
```

My Custom Adapter code is following

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhoneList> {
        int inflatr;
        Context ctxt;
        ArrayList<PhoneList> data=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PhoneList> arr) {

            super(context, resource, arr);
            this.inflatr = resource;
            this.ctxt = context;
            this.data= arr;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         UserHolder holder = null;
         View row = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(inflatr, parent, false);
             holder = new UserHolder();
             holder.textName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
             holder.stnumber=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mobilenum);
             holder.checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);

//           holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
             row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
             holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();            
        }

//      if(bulkflag)
//        {
//            holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            holder.checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//        }
//       holder.checked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//
//              public void onClick(View v) {
//
//                  if(holder.checked.isChecked())
//                  {
//                      selectedIds.add(recIdArr.get(reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox)));
//                      //System.out.println("position "+reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox));
//                  }
//                  else
//                  {
//                      selectedIds.remove(recIdArr.get(reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox)));
//                  }
//              }
//          });
         PhoneList dta=data.get(position);
         holder.checked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

                    data.get(position).setselect(!data.get(position).getSelect());
                    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }
        });
         holder.checked.setChecked(dta.getSelect());
         //holder.checked.setTag(position);
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    zoooommmm"+dta.getNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for(int i=1; i<=256; i++)
        {
            holder.textName.setText(dta.getName());
        }
        for(int j=1; j<=256; j++)
        {
            holder.stnumber.setText(dta.getNumber());
        }
//      holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    Siddiqueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+dta.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),ContactList.class);
//              String tName=dta.getName();
//              moreIntent.putExtra("Template",tName);
//              v.getContext().startActivity(moreIntent);
//               // ctxt.startActivity(ctxt,ContactList.class);
//          }
//      });
        return row;
    }
@Override
        public int getCount() {
    //      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        static class UserHolder {
            TextView textName;
            TextView textAddress;
            TextView textLocation;
            ImageButton btnEdit;
            Button btnDelete;
            TextView stnumber;
            CheckBox checked;
            }


    }

My phone List class is following...

    package com.example.sqliteapplication;

    public class PhoneList {
        String name;
        String number;
        boolean isSelected;
        public PhoneList(String string,String number) {
            super();
            this.name = string;
            this.number=number;
        }
        public void setselect(Boolean b)
        {
            this.isSelected=b;
        }
        public boolean getSelect()
        {
            return  isSelected;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
            }
        public void setNumber(String number)
        {
            this.number=number;
        }
        public String getNumber()
        {
            return number;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            }



    }
```

Comment: But what is your problem?

Comment: problem is that multiple check boxes checked when click in one row check box

Comment: Have you checked my solution in your previous post regarding this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603619/app-crashes-when-i-click-on-checkbox-in-contact-listview?noredirect=1#comment36233183_23603619

Comment: I edit as you telling me to change getview with your code

Comment: you want to save the state of checked check box or you want one checkbox checked at a time or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need set `checkBox` value in `getView` method like:

```
 holder.checked.setChecked(dta.getSelect());
```

and you need set listener or checkChangeListener for that, for updating `Select` value

so your getView method must be like:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserHolder holder = null;
         View row = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
           // yourCode

        }
        else
        {
          // your code
        }
         holder.checked.setOnClickListener(this);
         holder.checked.setChecked(dta.getSelect());
         holder.checked.setTag(position);   // you need this for getting position in onClick method
         // other code
```

and onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



    int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

    data.get(position).setselect(
            !data.get(position).getSelect());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: broo but when i scroll down then goes to above no  check box is checked but checked it when i scroll down

Comment: I don't get you, please describe better with an example

Comment: and please post new getView method, (with my changed)

Comment: holder.checked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

        data.get(position).setselect(!data.get(position).getSelect());
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
   }
  });
         holder.checked.setChecked(dta.getSelect());
I write this one but app is crash when i clicked on checkbox

Comment: did you have `holder.checked.setTag(position);` in your code? can you edit your question instead post your code in comment?

Comment: don't comment that, if comment that line you must get NPE, you need that for getting position in list

Comment: int position = (Integer) v.getTag(); that give a null pointer exception

Comment: did you un comment `holder.checked.setTag(position);`? see my edi